# How update the dictionary value in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
dic = {'key1': ['value 1','value2'],'key2':[[{'a':'123','b':[]}],[{'a':'231','b':['123','56']}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

expecting to modify the dataframe output if the key2 value 'b'==[] then replace with Null value

expected output

```
key1           key2 
value1         [{'a':'123', 'b':**Null**}]   
value2         [{'a':'231', 'b':['123','56']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
df['key2'] = df['key2'].apply(lambda x: [{k: v or np.nan for k, v in d.items()} for d in x])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      key1                                key2
0  value 1            [{'a': '123', 'b': nan}]
1   value2  [{'a': '231', 'b': ['123', '56']}]
```

---

*Note:* You can substitute `np.nan` for `None`

---

EDIT:

To restrict replacement only for key `b`:

```py
df['key2'] = df['key2'].apply(lambda x: [{k: v or np.nan if k == 'b' else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in x])
```

Comment: You might want to add `if k == 'b' else v` after `np.nan` in the list comprehension? because OP mentions only 'b'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loops:

```
for l in dic['key2']:  # or for l in df['key2']:
    for d in l:
        if 'b' in d and d['b'] == []:
            d['b'] = None

print(df)
```

*Note that using`df = pd.DataFrame(dic)` makes `df['key2]` and `dic['key2']` point to the same objects. Thus modifying either one also changes the other.*

Output:

```
      key1                                key2
0  value 1           [{'a': '123', 'b': None}]
1   value2  [{'a': '231', 'b': ['123', '56']}]
```